# Inequality $|\cos(k)| \geq \frac{1}{2^k}$ for $k\geq 0$

Tags: inequality, diophantine-approximation

**My question :** Is it true that $|\cos(k)| \geq \frac{1}{2^k}$ for all integers $k\geq 0$ ?

**What I tried :** I have checked with a computer that the inequality holds for
$0 \leq k \leq 4\times 10^5$. I can also show that the set of $k$ for which the inequality holds is infinite ; in fact, it has density at least $\frac{1}{2}$.
To see that :

**Lemma.** For $x\in{\mathbb R}$, one has $(*):|\cos(x+1)|+|\cos(x+2)| \geq \frac{3}{4}$.

**Corollary of lemma.** For $x\in{\mathbb R}$, either $|\cos(x+1)|\geq \frac{|\cos(x)|}{2}$ or $|\cos(x+2)|\geq \frac{|\cos(x)|}{4}$.

Putting $x=k$ in the corollary, we then see that if the inequality holds
for $k$, it will also hold for $k+1$ or $k+2$.

**Proof of lemma.** Let $f_1(x)=|\cos(x+1)|$ and $f_2(x)=|\cos(x+2)|$. Since
$f_1$ and $f_2$ are $\pi$-periodic, it suffices to show $(*)$ on $[0,\pi]$. Now,
write $[0,\pi]=I_1 \cup I_2 \cup I_3$ where $I_1=[0,\frac{\pi}{2}-1]$, $I_2=[\frac{\pi}{2}-1,\frac{3\pi}{2}-2]$ and $I_3=[\frac{3\pi}{2}-2,\pi]$. Then
$f_1$ and $f_2$ are concave on each of the $I_j$, so it suffices to check (*) on the endpoints, and this is easy.

UPDATE 04/09/2019 :  We can use the fact that $\pi$ has irrationality
measure at most $8$ (as explained in the accepted answer to [this older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535386/converge-or-diverge-sum-n-1-infty-frac-tann2n), thanks to i707107 for providing the link). Indeed (in all this section every inequality is meant to hold for all but finitely many $k$), denote by $a_k$ an integer such that $a_k\frac{\pi}{2}$ is closest possible to $k$, so that $$\Big|k-\frac{a_k\pi}{2}\Big| \leq \frac{\pi}{4}\tag{1}$$.

Then $\Big|\pi-\frac{2k}{a_k}\Big| \geq \frac{1}{a_k^8}$. Now $a_k \sim \frac{2k}{\pi}$, so $a_k \gt \frac{k}{\pi}$. It follows that $$\Big|\frac{a_k\pi}{2}-k\Big| \geq \frac{1}{2a_k^7} \geq \frac{\pi^8}{2^7k^7}\tag{2}$$.

There are then two cases :

If $a_k$ is even then $|\cos(k)|\geq Constant\geq \frac{1}{2^k}$. If, on the other hand, $a_k$ is odd, then then finite increments inequality yields $\Big|\frac{\cos(k)-\cos(\frac{a_k\pi}{2})}{k-\frac{a_k\pi}{2}}\Big| \geq Constant$ so that $|\cos(k)| \geq Constant \times |k-\frac{a_k\pi}{2}|$.

So my inequality holds for all except finitely many $k$.

Comment: Apply the fact that $\pi$ has a finite irrationality measure. Start with modifying the idea here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535386/converge-or-diverge-sum-n-1-infty-frac-tann2n to your problem.

Comment: @i707107 I've updated my question, taking your comment into account.

Comment: Looks great! If you use Mahler's result (irrationality measure of $\pi$ is bounded by $42$) and your computation up to $4\times 10^5$, then you might be able to remove "all but finite".

Comment: @i707107 What is this "Mahler's result" you just mentioned ? The upper bound 8 (which is much stronger than 42) is now known

Comment: Mahler proved that the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is bounded by $42$, but it entails $|\pi-\frac nm|> \frac 1{m^{42}}$ for all $n$ and $m\geq 2$. All other results on the irrationality measure of $\pi$ are $|\pi-\frac nm |> \frac 1{m^{\mu}}$ for $m\geq m_0$, with $m_0$ is not specified.

Comment: @i707107 thanks for the clarification, do you also remember more precisely where Mahler proved this ?

Comment: The paper is here: https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/mahler/collected.html#1950s (1953)On the approximation of $\pi$

Comment: @i707107 Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found a proof, based on i707107's suggestion. By using a computer
program with sufficient precision, one can check that the inequality holds
for $k<316$. So it will suffice to show the inequality for $k\geq 316$.

Denote by $a_k\frac{\pi}{2}$  the integral multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ that's closest to $k$, so that $\varepsilon_k=\big|k-a_k\frac{\pi}{2}\big| \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$. Then  $k=a_k\frac{\pi}{2}\pm\varepsilon_k$.

If $a_k$ is even, then $\cos(a_k\frac{\pi}{2})=\pm 1$ and hence $|\cos(k)|=|\cos(\varepsilon_k)| \geq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and we are done. So we may assume without loss that $a_k$ is odd.

Then $\cos(a_k\frac{\pi}{2})=0$. Using the finite increments formula, there is
a $\xi \in [a_k\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4},a_k\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}]$ such that $\frac{\cos(k)-\cos(a_k\frac{\pi}{2})}{k-a_k\frac{\pi}{2}}=-\sin(\xi)$. It follows that $\Big|\frac{\cos(k)-\cos(a_k\frac{\pi}{2})}{k-a_k\frac{\pi}{2}}\Big| \geq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, so that

$$
\begin{array}[lcl]
\big|\cos(k)\big| &\geq& \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \Big|k-a_k\frac{\pi}{2}\Big| \\
 &=& \frac{\sqrt{2}a_k}{4} \Big|\frac{2k}{a_k}-\pi\Big| \\
 &\geq& \frac{\sqrt{2}a_k}{4} \frac{1}{a_k^{42}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}a_k^{41}} \\
 &\geq& \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}\big(\frac{2k}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\big)^{41}} \\
\end{array}
$$

So, the inequality we want follows from

$$
2^{k} \geq \sqrt{8}\bigg(\frac{2k}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{41}
$$

which can be written as $f(k)\geq 0$ where $f(k)=2^{\frac{k-\frac{3}{2}}{41}}-\big(\frac{2k}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\big)$. We have
$f'(x)=\frac{\ln(2)}{41}2^{\frac{k-\frac{3}{2}}{41}}-\frac{2}{\pi}$ so that
$f'(x)\geq 0$ for $x\geq 3$. So for $k\geq 316$, we have $f(k)\geq f(316) \gt 0$
which finishes the proof.