# How to find functions which are "good (lower) bounds" of trigonometric sequences such as $\vert\sin(n)\vert$ and $1-\sin(n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I know that $\{ \sin(n): n\in\mathbb{N} \}\ $ is dense in $[0,1].$ Furthermore, $\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N},\ \sin(n)\neq 0.\ $ So I am wondering:

For each of the following, does there exist some minimal $p>0$ and some  $\ N\in\mathbb{N}\ $ such that

1. $\quad\frac{1}{n^p} < \vert\sin(n)\vert\quad \forall\ n\geq N$
2. $\quad\frac{1}{n^p} < 1-\sin(n)\quad \forall\ n\geq N$

?

Also, instead of $\ \quad\frac{1}{n^p},\ $ it might be better to not limit ourselves, and instead ask if there is a minimal $\ p\ $ so that $\ \quad\frac{a}{n^p} < \vert\sin(n)\vert\quad \forall\ n\geq N\ $ for some $a>0$. Furthermore, if $\ n^p\ $ doesn't work here, maybe something stronger like $\ 2^n\ $ does? I don't know...

Or maybe a better way to ask the question is: What functions are a "good lower bound" for each of the above functions $\ (\ \vert\sin(n)\vert\ $ and $\ 1-\sin(n)\ )$ ?

What methods are there to tackle such problems?

Comment: $\sin(n) \ne 0$ is interesting. Is it because $\sin(x) = 0 \iff \exists k \in \mathbb Z\left(x = \pi k\right)$ and $\pi k$ is never a natural number?

Comment: @Vivid Yes, exactly right.

Comment: Are the RHS of those inequalities supposed to have a $\max$? (like $\cdots<\displaystyle\max_{m\leq n} |\!\sin(m)|$ perhaps?) I'm almost certain that $\{\sin(n):n\geq N\}$ is also dense in $[-1,1]$ for any $N$.

Comment: This is related to the irrationality measure of $\pi$. A good place to start is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535386/converge-or-diverge-sum-n-1-infty-frac-tann2n  and several good problems were asked in this forum. Try searching $\sin n$ and read from these problems.

Comment: The title asks about "_upper_ bounds" but $1/n^p\lt |\sin(n)|$ would mean that $1/n^p$ is a _lower_ bound. Could you clarify which do you mean?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas thanks for pointing that out to me. I've edited the question accordingly. Eric Nathan Stucky- No it is not meant to have a max. Just because sin(n) is dense that doesn't address the question. And  Sungjin Kim - thank you for that link.